# Git pull/ Git push/ Git clone not working (SSL error 140770FC)

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, git-bash

I have a problem with **Git** and **Github** doing commit actions such as `git push` , `git pull` or even `git clone` on **Visual Studio Code** and Git Bash.

I get this error

> fatal: unable to access 'https://mygithub.com/myusername/testgit.git/': error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol

after attempting a `git push` which worked just fine a few days ago.

I have tried to update my Git (currently **2.19.1.windows.1** on **Windows 10**) by downloading again Git (so everything is up to date) according to another issue here but still didn't work out for me.

I initially cloned my project with a token with this command `git clone https://MyToken@mygithub.com/myusername/testgit.git` which worked weeks ago. I tried to access to the project through SSH method but get this error

> ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you still have access to the repository? I would check that first. 
If you still do: renew your ssh-keys (delete old, add new).
https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/

Comment: Yes, I still have access to the repository. I have renewed the ssh although I didn't delete the last one. Can this be a problem? I am going to test the ssh again to see if the new one works. Thank you for your input.

Comment: @Mr.Turtle I have checked the ssh key and I had forgotten to change the remote https to ssh. So that is done and the ssh is added and all. The first error message has gone (yay) however, now the second error message is on all three actions `git pull`, `git push`, `git clone`.

Comment: @Mr.Turtle I tested my ssh connection and I do have a new error : _ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first error, I had forgotten to change my git remote HTTPS to SSH. Follow the steps [here](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/#switching-remote-urls-from-https-to-ssh).

For the second error, I have a corporate internet so this was blocking my commit. I used my own phone internet and connected it to my computer and now it all works!